# Em que ocasiões um moderador deve ser acionado?

Tags: suporte, sinalização, moderadores

Gostaria de saber quando sinalizar uma pergunta com a opção "Precisa da atenção dos moderadores"?

***Local onde estou especificando***

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu diria que quando nenhuma das outras opções se encaixar.

Comment: @JorgeB. Sempre fiquei em dúvida nessa opção. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se houvesse uma lista formal de ocasiões, elas fariam parte das opções padrão, e não haveria um campo de texto livre.

Como muitas das ferramentas do site, é algo que depende do discernimento e bom senso de quem usa. Viu algo que você acredita estar errado, mas que não pode lidar você mesmo (seja votando contra, para fechar, apagar, etc)? E é algo que não se encaixa nas outras 4 opções?

Então descreva o problema para os moderadores que eles dão uma olhada.

Comment: entendi, vlw pela resposta 